# A system error occured. System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, webservice-client, system-error

when i try download all data from webservice take more time and finally coming with below error.

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsSql.ExecuteReader(IntPtr opsConCtx, IntPtr& opsErrCtx, IntPtr& opsSqlCtx, IntPtr& opsDacCtx, IntPtr& opsReaderErrCtx, IntPtr opsSubscrCtx, Int32& isSubscrRegistered, Int32 bchgNTFNExcludeRowidInfo, Int32 bQueryBasedNTFNRegistration, Int64& query_id, OpoSqlValCtx*& pOpoSqlValCtx, String pCommandText, OpoDacValCtx*& pOpoDacValCtx, IntPtr[] pOpoPrmValCtx, String[] ppOpoPrmRefCtx, OpoMetValCtx*& pOpoMetValCtx, Int32 NoOfParams)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.AbsClient.AbsCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

need solution to get all data from webservice.